# Regular winXP crashes, suspected memory, error 0xc0000017 among others

Tags: windows-xp, memory, crash

I'm running WinXP on a desktop machine I built in 2009. It's been successfully overclocked in the past, but I've brought it back to stock a while ago since one of the fans stopped working and it wasn't getting enough cooling  (one of the big system fans, the CPU fan is fine and all temperatures are fine).

Now, it will crash after a day and a half, or two if I leave it running. In the past it was running 24/7.

The symptoms are popups informing me that various background apps have crashed. If I don't "catch" it when it crashes, I'll get an infinite amount of popups and most running apps will be down. Sometimes I won't get any errors, programs will just stop working. Foobar2000 will crash and it will loop the last second of sound it was playing.

One of the recurring errors is 0xc0000017. (It's just a popup, no BSOD)

If I want to reboot via the start menu after the crash, I won't get the restart option, only to switch users or log off. If I log off and log back in, everything works fine.

I've tried swapping memory sticks around, tried with one, stick in each of the four slots with no luck. The CPU isn't overheating. The GPU is a bit hotter than normal, but it isn't under load when it crashes.

Here is a HijackThis logfile if it helps.

```
Logfile of Trend Micro HijackThis v2.0.5
Scan saved at 12:58:30 AM, on 10/14/2013
Platform: Windows XP SP3 (WinNT 5.01.2600)
MSIE: Internet Explorer v8.00 (8.00.6001.18702)
CHROME: 30.0.1599.69
FIREFOX: 24.0 (en-US)
Boot mode: Normal

Running processes:
C:\WINDOWS\System32\smss.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\winlogon.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\services.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\lsass.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe
C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\spoolsv.exe
C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mDNSResponder.exe
C:\Program Files\SearchProtect\bin\CltMngSvc.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\jqs.exe
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Skype\Toolbars\Skype C2C Service\c2c_service.exe
C:\Program Files\Alcohol Soft\Alcohol 120\StarWind\StarWindServiceAE.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\Wacom_Tablet.exe
C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\Version8\TeamViewer_Service.exe
C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE
C:\WINDOWS\system32\taskswitch.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\GrooveMonitor.exe
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\AdobeARM.exe
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Java\Java Update\jusched.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WTablet\Wacom_TabletUser.exe
E:\Downloads\QuickSoundSwitch.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\ctfmon.exe
C:\Documents and Settings\Sinisa\Local Settings\Apps\F.lux\flux.exe
C:\Documents and Settings\Sinisa\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\Wacom_Tablet.exe
C:\Documents and Settings\Sinisa\Application Data\SearchProtect\bin\cltmng.exe
C:\Program Files\WinSplit Revolution\WinSplit.exe
C:\Program Files\ubuntuone\dist\ubuntuone-syncdaemon.exe
C:\Program Files\ubuntuone\dist\ubuntuone-control-panel-qt.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wscntfy.exe
C:\Documents and Settings\Sinisa\Local Settings\Application Data\Facebook\Update\FacebookUpdate.exe
C:\Program Files\SugarSync\SugarSyncManager.exe
C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe
C:\Program Files\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe
C:\Program Files\Launchy\Launchy.exe
C:\Program Files\WinSplit Revolution\WinSplitDrvr32.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\devldr32.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wuauclt.exe
C:\Program Files\ubuntuone\dist\ubuntu-sso-login.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
E:\Downloads\HijackThis.exe

R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Default_Page_URL = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=69157
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Default_Search_URL = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R1 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Search Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54896
R0 - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main,Start Page = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=69157
R1 - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings,ProxyOverride = *.local
R3 - URLSearchHook: uTorrentControl_v6 Toolbar - {96f454ea-9d38-474f-b504-56193e00c1a5} - C:\Program Files\uTorrentControl_v6\prxtbuTor.dll
O2 - BHO: AcroIEHelperStub - {18DF081C-E8AD-4283-A596-FA578C2EBDC3} - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX\AcroIEHelperShim.dll
O2 - BHO: (no name) - {5C255C8A-E604-49b4-9D64-90988571CECB} - (no file)
O2 - BHO: Groove GFS Browser Helper - {72853161-30C5-4D22-B7F9-0BBC1D38A37E} - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\GrooveShellExtensions.dll
O2 - BHO: Java(tm) Plug-In SSV Helper - {761497BB-D6F0-462C-B6EB-D4DAF1D92D43} - C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\ssv.dll
O2 - BHO: Windows Live Sign-in Helper - {9030D464-4C02-4ABF-8ECC-5164760863C6} - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WindowsLiveLogin.dll
O2 - BHO: uTorrentControl_v6 - {96f454ea-9d38-474f-b504-56193e00c1a5} - C:\Program Files\uTorrentControl_v6\prxtbuTor.dll
O2 - BHO: SkypeIEPluginBHO - {AE805869-2E5C-4ED4-8F7B-F1F7851A4497} - C:\Program Files\Skype\Toolbars\Internet Explorer\skypeieplugin.dll
O2 - BHO: Java(tm) Plug-In 2 SSV Helper - {DBC80044-A445-435b-BC74-9C25C1C588A9} - C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\jp2ssv.dll
O3 - Toolbar: uTorrentControl_v6 Toolbar - {96f454ea-9d38-474f-b504-56193e00c1a5} - C:\Program Files\uTorrentControl_v6\prxtbuTor.dll
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [NVMixerTray] "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvMixer\NVMixerTray.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [CoolSwitch] C:\WINDOWS\system32\taskswitch.exe
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [GrooveMonitor] "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\GrooveMonitor.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Adobe ARM] "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\AdobeARM.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [QuickTime Task] "C:\Program Files\QuickTime Alternative\QTTask.exe" -atboottime
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [SunJavaUpdateSched] "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Java\Java Update\jusched.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [SearchProtectAll] C:\Program Files\SearchProtect\bin\cltmng.exe
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [QuickSoundSwitch] E:\Downloads\QuickSoundSwitch.exe
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [AlcoholAutomount] "C:\Program Files\Alcohol Soft\Alcohol 120\axcmd.exe" /automount
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [ctfmon.exe] C:\WINDOWS\system32\ctfmon.exe
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [F.lux] "C:\Documents and Settings\Sinisa\Local Settings\Apps\F.lux\flux.exe" /noshow
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [Google Update] "C:\Documents and Settings\Sinisa\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe" /c
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [Winsplit] C:\Program Files\WinSplit Revolution\WinSplit.exe
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [PeerBlock] C:\Program Files\PeerBlock\peerblock.exe
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [Ubuntu One] "C:\Program Files\ubuntuone\dist\ubuntuone-syncdaemon.exe"
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [Ubuntu One Icon] "C:\Program Files\ubuntuone\dist\ubuntuone-control-panel-qt.exe" --minimized
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [Facebook Update] "C:\Documents and Settings\Sinisa\Local Settings\Application Data\Facebook\Update\FacebookUpdate.exe" /c /nocrashserver
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [SugarSync] "C:\Program Files\SugarSync\SugarSyncManager.exe" -startInTray -usedelay=true
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [Skype] "C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /minimized /regrun
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [SearchProtect] C:\Documents and Settings\Sinisa\Application Data\SearchProtect\bin\cltmng.exe
O4 - HKCU\..\Run: [uTorrent] "C:\Program Files\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe"
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-19\..\Run: [CTFMON.EXE] C:\WINDOWS\system32\CTFMON.EXE (User 'LOCAL SERVICE')
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-20\..\Run: [CTFMON.EXE] C:\WINDOWS\system32\CTFMON.EXE (User 'NETWORK SERVICE')
O4 - HKUS\S-1-5-18\..\Run: [CTFMON.EXE] C:\WINDOWS\system32\CTFMON.EXE (User 'SYSTEM')
O4 - HKUS\.DEFAULT\..\Run: [CTFMON.EXE] C:\WINDOWS\system32\CTFMON.EXE (User 'Default user')
O4 - Startup: Launchy.lnk = C:\Program Files\Launchy\Launchy.exe
O8 - Extra context menu item: E&xport to Microsoft Excel - res://C:\PROGRA~1\MI1933~1\Office12\EXCEL.EXE/3000
O9 - Extra button: Send to OneNote - {2670000A-7350-4f3c-8081-5663EE0C6C49} - C:\PROGRA~1\MI1933~1\Office12\ONBttnIE.dll
O9 - Extra 'Tools' menuitem: S&end to OneNote - {2670000A-7350-4f3c-8081-5663EE0C6C49} - C:\PROGRA~1\MI1933~1\Office12\ONBttnIE.dll
O9 - Extra button: Skype Click to Call - {898EA8C8-E7FF-479B-8935-AEC46303B9E5} - C:\Program Files\Skype\Toolbars\Internet Explorer\skypeieplugin.dll
O9 - Extra button: Research - {92780B25-18CC-41C8-B9BE-3C9C571A8263} - C:\PROGRA~1\MI1933~1\Office12\REFIEBAR.DLL
O9 - Extra button: (no name) - {e2e2dd38-d088-4134-82b7-f2ba38496583} - C:\WINDOWS\Network Diagnostic\xpnetdiag.exe
O9 - Extra 'Tools' menuitem: @xpsp3res.dll,-20001 - {e2e2dd38-d088-4134-82b7-f2ba38496583} - C:\WINDOWS\Network Diagnostic\xpnetdiag.exe
O9 - Extra button: Messenger - {FB5F1910-F110-11d2-BB9E-00C04F795683} - C:\Program Files\Messenger\msmsgs.exe
O9 - Extra 'Tools' menuitem: Windows Messenger - {FB5F1910-F110-11d2-BB9E-00C04F795683} - C:\Program Files\Messenger\msmsgs.exe
O16 - DPF: {6414512B-B978-451D-A0D8-FCFDF33E833C} (WUWebControl Class) - http://update.microsoft.com/windowsupdate/v6/V5Controls/en/x86/client/wuweb_site.cab?1288894814484
O18 - Protocol: grooveLocalGWS - {88FED34C-F0CA-4636-A375-3CB6248B04CD} - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\GrooveSystemServices.dll
O18 - Protocol: skype-ie-addon-data - {91774881-D725-4E58-B298-07617B9B86A8} - C:\Program Files\Skype\Toolbars\Internet Explorer\skypeieplugin.dll
O18 - Protocol: skype4com - {FFC8B962-9B40-4DFF-9458-1830C7DD7F5D} - C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\Skype\SKYPE4~1.DLL
O22 - SharedTaskScheduler: Browseui preloader - {438755C2-A8BA-11D1-B96B-00A0C90312E1} - C:\WINDOWS\system32\browseui.dll
O22 - SharedTaskScheduler: Component Categories cache daemon - {8C7461EF-2B13-11d2-BE35-3078302C2030} - C:\WINDOWS\system32\browseui.dll
O23 - Service: Adobe Flash Player Update Service (AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc) - Adobe Systems Incorporated - C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\FlashPlayerUpdateService.exe
O23 - Service: Bonjour Service - Apple Inc. - C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mDNSResponder.exe
O23 - Service: Search Protect by Conduit Updater (CltMngSvc) - Conduit - C:\Program Files\SearchProtect\bin\CltMngSvc.exe
O23 - Service: FLEXnet Licensing Service - Acresso Software Inc. - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Macrovision Shared\FLEXnet Publisher\FNPLicensingService.exe
O23 - Service: Java Quick Starter (JavaQuickStarterService) - Oracle Corporation - C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\jqs.exe
O23 - Service: Mozilla Maintenance Service (MozillaMaintenance) - Mozilla Foundation - C:\Program Files\Mozilla Maintenance Service\maintenanceservice.exe
O23 - Service: NVIDIA Display Driver Service (NVSvc) - NVIDIA Corporation - C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvsvc32.exe
O23 - Service: ServiceLayer - Nokia - C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\ServiceLayer.exe
O23 - Service: Skype C2C Service - Skype Technologies S.A. - C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Skype\Toolbars\Skype C2C Service\c2c_service.exe
O23 - Service: Skype Updater (SkypeUpdate) - Skype Technologies - C:\Program Files\Skype\Updater\Updater.exe
O23 - Service: StarWind AE Service (StarWindServiceAE) - Rocket Division Software - C:\Program Files\Alcohol Soft\Alcohol 120\StarWind\StarWindServiceAE.exe
O23 - Service: TabletServiceWacom - Wacom Technology, Corp. - C:\WINDOWS\system32\Wacom_Tablet.exe
O23 - Service: TeamViewer 8 (TeamViewer8) - TeamViewer GmbH - C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\Version8\TeamViewer_Service.exe
O23 - Service: wampapache - Apache Software Foundation - c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.11\bin\httpd.exe
O23 - Service: wampmysqld - Unknown owner - c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin\mysqld.exe

--
End of file - 10563 bytes
```

I'm at a loss on what to do next.

Thanks

Comment: Your telling us your CPU doesn't have a working fan?  Thats a problem you will solve before we can help.

Comment: Sorry, the CPU has a working fan, it's the big fan at the back of the case that isn't working. The case is open and I have a room fan blowing. The temperatures show up all fine on a monitoring program except for GPU. But the symptoms don't match a GPU crash

Comment: You don't indicate any information about what I believe is a BSOD ( your not clear on that ) a error code without the drivers and systems files that were loaded is sort of useless.

Comment: It is not a BSOD. I indicated that I can still use the start menu, log off and log back on.

Answer (score 0):

The error code 0xc0000017 means 2 things:

> C:\Users\André>err 0xc0000017
>
> ## for hex 0xc0000017 / decimal -1073741801   STATUS_NO_MEMORY                                               ntstatus.h
>
> ## {Not Enough Quota}
>
> ## Not enough virtual memory or paging file quota is available
>
> ## to complete the specified operation.
>
> ## as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_NULL (0x0), Code 0x17
>
> ## for hex 0x17 / decimal 23   ERROR_CRC                                                      winerror.h
>
> ## Data error (cyclic redundancy check).
>
> ## 2 matches found for "0xc0000017"

So check that your pagefile is large enough and the HDD cables are ok.

Comment: never seen the `err` command before, and it doesn't resolve on my system. is it an external tool?

Comment: @FrankThomas **err.exe** is part of the windows 7 SDK